# when do java infinite loops stop?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop, garbage-collection

I read about infinite loops and found out in some languages it will stop when stack overflows or reached the allotted maximum memory. Others will loop forever depending on the type of program and language.
My question is, do java infinite loops stop? I'm just curious because java has a garbage collector, that reuse memory when there's memory leak in case of reaching allotted maximum memory and stack overflow.

Also,will this kind of infinite loop stop?

```
for( ; ; ){}
```

Comment: This won't ever stop, the only time an infinite loop will stop is if it is leaking memory or doing some sort of recursion. hopefully someone else can give you a more thorough answer

Comment: This loop won't stop because it will never start in the first place. Java's optimizing compiler will see that the loop does no work and has no side effects and eliminate the dead code.

Comment: They stop when time runs out :)  Or the process is killed.

Comment: @Andrew Bissell - When I try this, both Eclipse and the JRE gave me an error about unreachable code after the loop. If there is no code after the loop, it still executes and never gets past it.

Comment: @AndrewBissell well, if you declare a variable like `boolean run = true` and use `while(run) { }` it will pass, as it can be changed by other thread, but if there's no change, you get an infinite loop.

Comment: [Just don't do it.](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MSC01-J.+Do+not+use+an+empty+infinite+loop) (From the link, "An infinite loop with an empty body consumes CPU cycles but does nothing. Optimizing compilers and just-in-time systems (JITs) are permitted to (perhaps unexpectedly) remove such a loop. Consequently, programs must not include infinite loops with empty bodies.")

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think no one is thinking in doing that for practical use, its just a didactic question. Well the fact its called infinite loop should be sufficient, but anyway.

Comment: Actually, @David, any JIT compiler that removes that infinite loop is not following the JLS, specifically 14.14.1.1-3, which spell out in great detail that the only way for a `for` statement to complete normally if there's no continuation expression is via the use of `break`. You can end the loop if the evaluation of the expression terminates abruptly but that's not possible since there _is_ no expression. It can also end abruptly if you do certain things in the body as well but again, you're not doing _anything_ in the body.

Comment: @paxdiablo The specification allows the optimizer to assume a loop will eventually terminate. The alternative would penalize a lot of code.

Comment: @David, it would be useful if you cited your source. From what I can see in the JLS, code has to be reachable as per 14.21 but there seems to be no requirement there that it has to _complete normally._ Of course, if there's code in the method _after_ the infinite loop, _that_ code will be unreachable hence a compile error. But that doesn't make the infinite loop itself illegal. For example, this compiles and runs fine: `class Test{public static void main(String[]args){for(;;){}}}`

Comment: @paxdiablo It's not that it's illegal, it's that the optimizer is permitted to assume it will eventually terminate. The idea is to allow the optimizer to remove expensive loops if it can prove the loop can have no effects other than, perhaps, to fail to ever stop. This is a realistic case and the alternative would be to require lots of expensive computation that we know for a fact can have no effects just to prove the loop eventually terminates.

Comment: @David, I'm not doubting you're right, just stating that it appears to disagree with the plain wording in the JLS. Appealing to common sense (while handy) is not really a citation :-) I was hoping for something else in the JLS that stated infinite loops could be optimised out of existence but I could find nothing there. Maybe Oracle has another document that states this, one that overrides the JLS. Still, I wouldn't spend any more time on it unless you know off the top of your head where it is. Cheers.

Comment: A comment on "in some languages". Whether this sort of loop stops without intervention depends less on the language and more on what the loop does. If it allocates more memory than it frees (either explicitly or by letting it become unreachable) or if it pushes more stack frames than it pops, it will run out of resources, regardless of language.

Answer (score 7):

> My question is, do java infinite loops stop?

Some do, some don't.  It depends on how the loop is implemented.

Basically the cases that you identified as stopping in other languages *could* also stop in Java ... depending on how you code them.

- A stack overflow will occur with a loop that is implemented by infinite recursion.  That is easier to "achieve" in Java than in some languages.  (No tail call optimization.)
- A heap overflow will occur if the loop repeatedly allocates objects that remain reachable ... so that the GC is unable to reclaim them.

(And there are various other ways that a *seemingly* infinite loop can terminate.)

> I'm just curious because java has a garbage collector, that reuse memory when there's memory leak in case of reaching allotted maximum memory and stack overflow.

The garbage collector reclaims unreachable objects, but objects that are reachable (i.e. that that *could* be used by the program in the future) cannot be reclaimed.

The garbage collector does not deal with stack memory, so it is not relevant to stack overflow failures.

> Also,will this kind of infinite loop stop?

No.

---

Strictly speaking, any loop is NOT infinite if it stops ... for any reason.  That includes reasons such as stack overflow or memory exhaustion.

But even infinite loops are not truly infinite.  Eventually the user is going to kill the looping program, the power will fail, the hardware will be scrapped ... or something like that.

Comment: I don't think anyone thinks of "infinite" in "infinite loop" as being mathematical infinity. It's more like "a loop that continues without any effective limit".

Comment: @TedHopp - I'm sure *someone* thinks that.  Indeed, I'd be surprised if some people *don't* find this point a bit confusing ... to start with.  Also it is exceedingly difficult to define what "without any effective limit" actually means.  Therefore, it is worth mentioning these issue ... IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Infinite loops do *not* stop, absent some other reason for the whole thing falling to pieces :-)

That's usually a shortage of resources, be it stack space in the case of infinite *recursion,* or running out of memory because you're allocating some (and not freeing it) in the loop.

Garbage collection only throws away *garbage.* Memory is not considered garbage if it can still be reached by your variables.

In other words, if your infinite loop adds an element to the end of a linked list each time through (and you don't lose access to the head), *none* of those nodes will be garbage-collected and you will eventually run out of memory.

That particular loop of yours:

```
for (;;) {}
```

won't actually stop since it's not using any resources. Of course, you can kill the process, or you may have a separate thread which uses resources. Both these (and other events) may result in the loop stopping but they're all outside the control of that loop.

Answer (score 2):

An infinite loop can stop because of the memory if the memory grows in the loop. In this case, there is no memory grow.

But, if you create some new heavy objects in every iteration of the loop, then it will stop eventually due to a Memory Limit Exception.

Comment: Regarding your second point: that's only true if hard references to the objects are also maintained (i.e., don't go out of scope, so the heavy objects don't become garbage).

Comment: @TedHopp, right, in other words, creating those objects inside another object that is outside the scope of the loop.